# Appropriate site for question about Google Groups?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

I was about to ask a question on Super User about problems I've been having accessing Google Groups, but then I noticed that *a lot* of questions on that site having to do with web apps were being closed as not relevant.  If that's the case, what would be the right place to ask the question?  If there's a different site in the Stack Overflow family that would be appropriate, it would be good for the users/admins of Super User to send people to that site.

Answer (score 3):

It seems [a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) for these sorts of issues is destined to come to life

Answer (score 3):

The site is live: [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

Here are proposals on Area51 that might cover your needs if they are launched:

**Web Apps Site**

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications?referrer=cim4F0_TQeo1

**Google Site**

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1318/google?referrer=SwZU-ceNHZ41

(Disc:  Referral links)

Comment: Thanks for linking to the proposed Google site as well as the Web Applications one. As it turns out, I think I agree with those who question the need for a Google-specific site, but it gave me the chance ponder the matter.